# "flat," "stone," "dead," "dirt," "plumb," and "right" as indicators of directness, completeness, or general intensity

Tags: american-english, word-usage, dialects, colloquialisms, non-standard

What's the difference between those words? Can they be used just about interchangeably as adverbs indicating completeness or totality?

Please, compare:

> *Looking back over my years of wildlife work, there are only two things that I'm **plumb** sure of: it's not easy work to prepare for or get into, but it's worth it.* [Out Home](https://books.google.fr/books?id=IEJxYA133k8C&pg=PA184&lpg=PA184&dq=%22things+that+i%27m+plumb+sure%22&source=bl&ots=qeUBz1T3H3&sig=PdmUMmLvFZ2emzZpb74GvY5eAu0&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjwqoubhovLAhVL2hoKHbcvDrEQ6AEIGjAA#v=onepage&q=%22things%20that%20i%27m%20plumb%20sure%22&f=false)
>
> *Looking back over my years of wildlife work, there are only two things that I'm **dead** sure of [...]*
>
> *Looking back over my years of wildlife work, there are only two things that I'm **dirt** sure of [...]*
>
> *Looking back over my years of wildlife work, there are only two things that I'm **flat** sure of [...]*
>
> *Looking back over my years of wildlife work, there are only two things that I'm **stone** sure of [...]*
>
> *Looking back over my years of wildlife work, there are only two things that I'm **right** sure of [...]*

-and-

> *I'm right tired tonight. I think I'll go on over to my digs and get me a long night's sleep.* [Bullet for a Half-Breed](https://books.google.fr/books?id=Ab-YrEgtWV4C&pg=PT53&lpg=PT53&dq=%22i%27m+right+tired%22&source=bl&ots=PcG2a1hVki&sig=p6g55NXs3kALxc2_7g859maVWKY&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjYosWWuIvLAhUGuhoKHSHcDLcQ6AEINjAI#v=onepage&q=%22i%27m%20right%20tired%22&f=false)
>
> *I'm [**dirt**](https://www.google.fr/search?q=%22i%27m+right+tired%22&hl=fr&prmd=ivsn&source=lnms&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjZosaSuIvLAhWJ1xoKHU6tC04Q_AUIBigA&biw=1024&bih=672&dpr=2#hl=fr&q=%22i%27m+dirt+tired%22) tired tonight. [...]*
>
> *I'm **dead** tired tonight. [...]*
>
> *I'm **plumb** tired tonight. [...]*
>
> *I'm **flat** tired tonight. [...]*
>
> *I'm **stone** tired tonight. [...]*

Comment: How do you intend to use them? In speech? Writing? With what context? I ask because, well, for example, they're all colloquial, and perhaps all localisms and regionalisms in addition. So, used in speech or writing, they may be mostly interchangable in meaning, but if you used the wrong one in the wrong place at the wrong time, you'd mark yourself as an outsider, a pretender, meet with noncomprehension, strike a dissonant note, or etc. So, how interchangable they are depends on the context of use.

Comment: @JEL The question is posed out of sheer curiosity, since I can't seem to find any resources online dealing with how to use these colloquialisms, how they might subtly differ from each other, etc. https://www.google.fr/search?q=%22I'm+dirt+sure%22&biw=484&bih=318&source=lnms&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjHztHXkYvLAhXBOxoKHYrPB78Q_AUIBygA&dpr=2#q=%22dead%22+%22dirt%22+%22plumb%22+%22flat%22+%22stone%22+%22right%22+adverbs+completeness+intensity Inquiring minds want to know...:)

Comment: "Flat sure", "stone sure", and "dirt sure" are not things I've ever heard. I've heard "dirt poor", but generally dirt isn't used as a modifier outside of that. Stone is more for "stone cold".

Comment: @QPaysTaxes  I think it's on ELU that I read a comment from a native speaker of AmEng saying that "dirt" is commonly used as an intensifier in their neck of the woods. I seem to remember he or she was from the South... http://michellemalkin.com/2009/10/16/blackballing-conservatism/

Comment: The obvious thing to do is to check collocability (1) in a dictionary of collocations and (2) online. I have a long list of these secondary / degree modifiers (though these particular examples are in a subset not ending in -ly); and their distribution (other than for say 'very' and a few others) tends to be very idiosyncratic. The ones listed here are usually only used in informal to slang registers, with a few exceptions (eg _dead ahead, Right Honourable_).

Comment: "Dirt" is not something I've often (if ever) seen/heard in this context.  "Plumb" and "dead" are probably most often used, but there are places where one may be idiomatic and the other not.  (Note that "dirt" is not used as a simple intensifier in "dirt poor" but is describing the fact that all the person has is dirt, and not much of that.)

Comment: Here is a list of some collocations involving non-ly-form secondary- (adjective-) modifiers:  blind drunk  /  dead straight  /  dead slow  /  dirty great            fast asleep    /     filthy rich   /
flat broke    /      mad keen     /     plain stupid     /     plumb loco    /     sore afraid    /   squeaky clean    /   wide awake        /       downright idiotic     /     drop-dead gorgeous       /       lead pipe cinch       /       stone cold sober    /   vivid green     /  {[a] tired green}     /   stony broke. They're all intensifiers, but some are not semantically bleached.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - are *any* of them semantically bleached ? (great concept!)

Comment: *plumb tuckered out*  ??!

Comment: Fast asleep and plumb loco certainly are. I'd say most of these are bleached to a large degree. But one man's metaphor is another man's dead metaphor.

Comment: They are all colloquial variants for very.

Comment: @HotLicks Yeah, I think you're 'right' right about that... "Speakers of Standard English mainly restrict the use of adverbial right to modify adverbs of space or time, as in 'She's right over there' or 'Do it right now!' No such restriction applies in Southern vernacular speech, where right can be used to intensify the meaning of many adjectives and adverbs, as in 'He's right nice' or 'You talk right fast.' This broader use of right is attested as far back as the 1400s and is found in the works of Shakespeare and other great writers." Source: FOD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the words you cite can mean pretty much the same thing.  They are all colourful/regional/socio-economic variants of *extremely/absolutely/completely*.  Their idiomatic usage depends not only on regional and social factors but also on the desired formality/objectivity of the communication.

They *cannot* be used interchangeably in most circumstances.

Consider the following examples:

If I have no money I am ***flat*** broke.

The man who had not been seen for a few days was found in his bed,  ***stone*** dead.

The race was so close that it ended in a ***dead*** heat.

The people at the end of the road are ***dirt*** poor ('***dead***' could be used here as well).

If I do a very silly thing I am being ***plumb*** crazy/stupid.

If I live at one end of a long road I may describe this location as being ***right*** at the end of the road.

Although all the words in bold carry the same meaning ONLY the word used works for me (none of the others on your list, except in the case indicated).

For me, the words evoke ... (this could be refined with time for reflection!)

***Flat*** - featureless plains, tyres and hospital monitors;

***Stone*** - hard, unyielding, cold;

***Dead*** - non-negotiable;

***Dirt*** - Without human/capital investment;

***Plumb*** - Without deviation, heavy, bottomless

The point is, you may not agree with my usages and associations, but you will almost certainly find that others will not agree with yours either!

I would avoid using *all* of these words unless you are confident the usage rings true.

Comment: + for going into the nuances in meaning. Regionional uses from local vernacular/work terminology could have started some of these modifiers. For instance 'Plumb X' might have originated from the use of plumb-lines to determine vertical straitness or deviation from center.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend not using ANY of them at all, since they are all colloquialisms.  In context, their purpose is simply to add emphasis, similar to having a swear word in there, but without causing offence like a swear word might.

It's possible that they are all polite alternatives to the words *damn* or *damned*, but they also seem to relate to the process of building/repairing things, suggesting that there's a connotation that "I'm as sure of this as I am of something that i measured with a plumb line and thus know to be perfectly vertical", or "I'm as sure of this as i am of the stability of a house which is built on a stone foundation".  If this is the case then they have their origins in **metaphor** rather than as a polite alternative to swearing.

Either way, since their sole purpose is to add emphasis, I would recommend  replacing them with a word which does this more clearly and unambiguously, such as *very* or *extremely*.

With special reference to "dirt" - like a commenter said, i've only ever seen this used in the phrase "dirt poor", and there it has a special meaning, that the subject *subsists from the land they live on*.  It's not interchangeable at all with the others.

Comment: 'Dead centre' and 'dead ahead' are not colloquial usages. 'Dead slow' may be. And right in 'Right Honourable' is as formal as it gets.

Comment: "Right honourable" is only ever used within the English legal/parliamentary system, and can only be used to refer to an individual, usually "the right honourable gentleman".  So it doesn't really have any relevance: if the speaker in question proceeded to say "I'm right sure that this law discriminates against poor people" they would be laughed out of the building.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - It's probably no longer used, but "dead slow" was once a naval term for proceeding at the slowest possible speed.  In that context it's not colloquial.

Comment: @Hot Licks Yes; 'may' as in 'can' as opposed to 'is perhaps'.

Comment: 'dirt cheap' - cheap as dirt

Comment: @Mitch oh yeah.